# XML 1 line to multiline list XML format in C#

Tags: c#, html, xml, format

Hello I try to find solution to sort my 1 line XML return string to multiline formatted HTML XML
list.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><hierarchy rotation="0"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/b3" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1418]" /></node><node index="1" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/b2p" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,58][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/day" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,58][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,58][720,135]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/n9" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="Back" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[11,58][88,135]" /><node index="1" text="miakhalifa" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/title_tv" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[289,78][430,115]" /></node><node index="1" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/dwk" class="android.widget.HorizontalScrollView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,135][720,212]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,135][720,212]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$a" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[36,135][249,212]"><node index="0" text="Following 1216" resource-id="android:id/text1" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[57,157][228,189]" /></node><node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$a" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="true" bounds="[265,135][499,212]"><node index="0" text="Followers 23.6M" resource-id="android:id/text1" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="true" bounds="[286,157][478,189]" /></node><node index="2" text="" resource-id="" class="androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar$a" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[515,135][680,212]"><node index="0" text="Suggested" resource-id="android:id/text1" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[536,157][659,189]" /></node></node></node><node index="2" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,212][720,213]" /><node index="3" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/ew8" class="androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,213][720,1418]"><node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,213][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/doi" class="android.view.ViewGroup" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="false" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,213][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/d_1" class="androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,213][720,1418]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,213][720,216]" /><node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,216][720,342]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/bz8" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,230][126,328]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/bl4" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,230][126,328]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,230][126,328]" /></node></node><node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,247][516,311]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,247][293,279]"><node index="0" text="dg_modified" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/eo8" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,247][293,279]" /></node><node index="1" text="dillon_gorton" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/eng" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,286][516,311]" /></node><node index="2" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/enl" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,252][692,305]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,252][692,305]"><node index="0" text="Follow" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/vg" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,252][692,305]" /></node></node></node><node index="2" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,342][720,468]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/bz8" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,356][126,454]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/bl4" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,356][126,454]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,356][126,454]" /></node></node><node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,373][516,437]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,373][247,405]"><node index="0" text="vnivicela" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/eo8" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,373][247,405]" /></node><node index="1" text="Nessa" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/eng" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,412][516,437]" /></node><node index="2" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/enl" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,378][692,431]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,378][692,431]"><node index="0" text="Follow" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/vg" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,378][692,431]" /></node></node></node><node index="3" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,468][720,594]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/bz8" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,482][126,580]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/bl4" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,482][126,580]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,482][126,580]" /></node></node><node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,499][516,563]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,499][247,531]"><node index="0" text="dudisxd1" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/eo8" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,499][247,531]" /></node><node index="1" text="user7061285582421" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/eng" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,538][516,563]" /></node><node index="2" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/enl" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,504][692,557]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,504][692,557]"><node index="0" text="Follow" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/vg" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,504][692,557]" /></node></node></node><node index="4" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,594][720,720]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/bz8" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,608][126,706]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/bl4" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,608][126,706]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,608][126,706]" /></node></node><node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,625][516,689]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,625][266,657]"><node index="0" text="nick86712" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/eo8" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,625][266,657]" /></node><node index="1" text="Phub" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/eng" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,664][516,689]" /></node><node index="2" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/enl" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,630][692,683]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,630][692,683]"><node index="0" text="Follow" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/vg" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,630][692,683]" /></node></node></node><node index="5" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,720][720,846]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/bz8" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,734][126,832]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/bl4" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,734][126,832]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[28,734][126,832]" /></node></node><node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,751][516,815]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,751][307,783]"><node index="0" text="user32174351" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/eo8" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,751][307,783]" /></node><node index="1" text="Ř´Ř®ŘµŮŠŘŞŮŠ" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/eng" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[147,790][516,815]" /></node><node index="2" text="" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/enl" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,756][692,809]"><node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,756][692,809]"><node index="0" text="Follow" resource-id="com.zhiliaoapp.musically:id/vg" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.zhiliaoapp.musically" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[542,756][692,809]" /></node></node></node>
```

I can do it via online HTML beautifier but I dont know how to do it in C#, is there some class which do it on auto?

Comment: You can easily do it via LINQ to XML

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\test.xml");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }
    }
}
```